# How to GSM Encode using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, gsm

I am having trouble with encoding the '#' character for a SMS based product.
The SMS is sent using a GET request to the API provided by the SMS Gateway provider. I am required to send a simple message "Dial #121#", but the SMS received on the Phone does not show the '#' character.

The application is built on Spring Boot and I am using the RestTemplate to make the request

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String message = "Dial #121#"; //example message
String baseUri = "http://api.example.com?msisdn=1234567&message=" + message;
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUri, String.class);
```

**Output on Phone** : Dial

**Expected Output** : Dial #121#

Please Assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by using the `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient` http clinet instead of Sprint Rest Template

Answer (score 1):

I think you first encode your URL:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String message = "Dial #121#"; //example message
String baseUri = "http://api.example.com?msisdn=1234567&message={message}";
URI expanded = new UriTemplate(baseUri ).expand(message);
baseUri = URLDecoder.decode(expanded.toString(), "UTF-8");
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUri, String.class);
```

Comment: Hi Chao, I am still getting the same output.

Comment: Can you make sure the url http://api.example.com?msisdn=1234567&message=Dial #121#    return the correct response?. How about http://api.example.com?msisdn=1234567&message='Dial #121#' ?

Comment: The url returns the expended result when the message param is set as :
**Dial %23121%23**

Comment: Got your point, someone report the issue to Spring: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14441 , you can refer this.

Comment: Thanks Chao, but I switched to ** org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient  ** 
 to make the request which provides the expected result.